# Win95 programming for Win8

Tags: windows, winapi, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I know some of you will think this silly, but I want to compile a Windows program on Win95 that will run on Win95/98/98SE/2K/ME/XP/VD/7/8 but not necessarily WinCE/3.1/RT as they don't implement Win32 API natively. I realize the Win32 API has evolved since its Win95 specification, but it should be backwards compatible as that is the main reason people use Windows as I understand it. What levels of API emulation must take place to make this possible? How does WinVD/7/8 implement compatibility? I ask so that I can write windows software that runs as seamlessly as possible across the Windows OSes.

Also, while slightly different but related, is it possible to cross-compile for Metro from other Windows distributions or from Mac or Linux? I realize debugging or running wouldn't be possible but I figure compilation should be.

Comment: This is silly.  No way that floppy disk drive still works.  Above all, no way you are going to find a customer that will pay you for a win95 program.  Even if you do find one, there's no way you'll want to support him.

Comment: Supporting Windows 95 and 98 is not unheard of, even today.  My last job involved a product that had to support 95 through XP.  In a global audience, you'll find a wide swath of usage patterns.  There were ugly UI warts with our product when you ran it on 95 or 98, but it was essentially functional.  The biggest problem was that the 9x versions weren't natively Unicode and we couldn't include unicows.dll with our package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem. If you can compile and run a program on Windows 95, that same program should run on Windows 98, ME, 2000, XP, Vista, 7 and 8. But you'll probably need an old development environement such as Visual Studio 6.

But if you are writing a program that should run on Win 95, you cannot use the APIs that have been introduced after Windows 95.

But honestly today there are not many reasons why Windows 95 should be supported.

Seel also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx).

Comment: "But if you are writing a program that should run on Win 95, you cannot use the APIs that have been introduced after Windows 95."  Yes you can.  You simply have to delay-load them at runtime, that's all. If you are using a modern IDE that supports delay-loading, then the linker can handle that for you automatically. Otherwise, you can simply call `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` manually. Either way gives the code a chance to do OS version checks before calling the functions, as well as allows for error handling and fallback to other code when the desired functions are not available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that's not quite correct, for example the SetLayeredWindowAttributes function in User32.dll has been introduced only in Windows 2000, so you simply cannot use this function in Windows 95/98. All you can do is use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() to get the address of SetLayeredWindowAttributes and use some fallback scheme if the function doesn't exist.

Comment: you just re-phrased and confirmed what I said earlier. You CAN write code that uses a DLL function from a newer OS, you just have to delay-load the function at run-time so you can skip it when it is not available.  Either let the linker set that logic up automatically if it natively supports delay loading, otherwise you have to call `GetProcAddress()` manually in your code (the linker's delay-load logic uses `GetProcAddress()` internally).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: OK so that was just a misunderstanding.